# Can you rescue Valentina Galkina?

Tags: arma-2

In the first combat mission in the ArmA 2 main campaign (Mission 2, "Into the Storm") you can rescue Valentina Galkina from getting abused by some OpFor soldiers in a house in Pusta (that is unless you totally miss what's going on in one of the houses). She re-appears in Mission 7, "Manhattan", but so far (at least for me) only as a corpse, with some local policemen on the crime scene explaining that she was caught by a bunch of Chedaki militias and executed on the spot.

Is there a way to rescue her a second time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This guide](http://guides.gamepressure.com/arma2/guide.asp?ID=7983) seems to imply that you can.

Relevant part here:

> WARNING 2 : If you saved previously doctor Sova and Valentina Galkina, you'll meet them here. Sova lives in Krasnystav. Valentina is on move in red car. Both have some information about sentry posts. If you won't meet them in advance – some bad guys will kill them.

During that meeting, if you shoot out the tires to her car, then she won't be killed later by the bad guys.

If you did rescue her the first time, and she was killed, then you may have experienced a glitch.

Comment: Sadly the guide doesn't tell if their death is scripted, or something you can prevent - just that you can meet them again alive if you're fast enough. Well then, off to fire up the mission again, see if I can find her red car (the map is huge though ...) and proceed to stalk her ... FOR SCIENCE!

Comment: it does imply though that she'll give you some intel if you meet her, so it may be possible to save her.  Good luck :)

Comment: [Looks like there might be a way to use that encounter to save her](http://forums.bistudio.com/showthread.php?94585-Saving-Valentina-in-Manhatten), but it involves shooting out the tires of her car (which is roughly what I did too - couldn't find any other way). Do you think you can edit the answer to incorporate the info I linked? I'll accept it either way, since the important part is you can meet her alive - and then it matters what you do for her to survive.